# Surgery for algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, blow-ups, surgery-theory

I have a number of vague questions that I wasn't sure whether they are suitable to ask or not, but I decided to ask!

According to [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9904135.pdf) result, any two birational varieties can be constructed by a sequence of blow-ups and blow-downs from each other. (There are more conditions on the theorem but I am simplifying it). The way I see this theorem is that it makes each class of birational varieties very combinatorial in a sense. It means if you have access to one variety in a birational class you can constructed the rest of them by very specific types of operations.

1. I was wondering whether there are a certain simple class of operations/surgeries that can make it possible to move from any variety to the other one (of fixed dimension and possibly only smooth varieties)?
2. I was wondering if we add finite covers (not necessarily etale) to blow ups and blow-downs does it make moving between any two varieties possible? (I know finite covers are not quite surgeries but that is what came to my mind!)(The answer to this is positive but I don't think it implies anything regarding question 3.)
3. Assume a certain statement has this property that if it is true for a finite cover then it is true for the base. Also it is a birational invariant. Is there any smallest family of specific varieties that you need only to prove the statement for that family in order to prove it for all varieties of the same dimension?

Comment: Any projective variety of dimension $d$ is a finite cover of $\mathbb{P}^d$: just embed the variety in one big projective space and keep projecting away from points. So the answer to your question 2. is yes, if I interpreted it correctly.

Comment: Yes you are right. This is basically Noether's normalization.

Comment: Re question 3: The answer should be no for any formalization of this question (basically because by passing to finite covers you generally cannot make the variety less complicated). For instance, for every family of varieties, a very general hypersurface of large degree will admit no birational morphisms from any member of that family.

Comment: @dhy I don't quite understand your argument. The family doesn't need to be bounded. For example you can take it to be product of curves. Now why no covering of a hypersurface of large degree can be birational to a product of curves?

Comment: @user127776 It is true that my argument does not apply to that case. More generally though, statements of the form "every variety has a nice finite cover" tend to be false, which is unfortunate because they would be extremely useful. P.S. the case of products of curves has some interesting history behind it: see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98771/varieties-dominated-by-products-of-curves

Comment: "it makes each class of birational varieties very combinatorial": Maybe for surfaces where all you need to do is blow up repeatedly at points, but not for anything else where you need to blow up some complicated subvariety. Pinkham has a paper about factorisation of birational maps which has some examples of how you can factorise certain 3-fold flops; the conclusion is that this is too complicated to be practical for most birational maps.

Comment: @dhy That is interesting. I wonder whether at the time it was known whether the Weil conjecture is a birationally invariant statement. The counter-examples seem to suggest that might not have been the case. It might be true if we consider the varieties up to birational equivalence.

Comment: @Jonny Evans You are right, I had mostly surfaces in my mind.

Comment: @user127776 Considering the varieties up to birational equivalence often doesn't do anything because of the following fact: If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a birational morphism of smooth projective varieties and $Y$ contains no rational curves, then in fact $f$ is a literal (biregular) morphism.

Comment: @dhy Did you mean to say "$X$ contains no rational curves"? Surely if we start with $Y$ containing no rational curves and blow up a smooth point, we now have rational curves in the exceptional divisor.

Comment: @TabesBridges Sorry, "birational" and "biregular" in my previous comment should have been "rational" and "regular."